# STL containers element destruction order

Tags: c++, stl, portability

Does ISO C++ standard mandate any sort of destruction order of objects inside STL containers?

- Are `std::list`/`std::vector`/`std::map` elements destroyed starting from the beginning or the end of the container?
- Can I rely on `std::map` storing its elements in `std::pair`s internally so a key in a pair is destroyed before its value (or vice versa)?

Comment: It is probably unspecified, but for `std::list` is for sure either in order or in reverse order since there is no other way to go through the elements (without doing extra work).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Unspecified in the standard.
2. Yes, but this means that the key is destroyed *after* its associated value.

Comment: #2, yep, that's what I meant, should've written the other way around. Can you point me to the part of the standard that specifies #2?

Comment: 20.2.2/1, and this ties in with my comments on Terry's answer.

Comment: @Roger Pate: Include that in the answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Unspecified
2. Yes, you can depend on std::map storing it's elements in std::pairs, but I don't see anything which specifies the Key portion of a std::pair being destructed before a Value portion.

Comment: The standard mandates *first* and *second* data members and shows them in that order, which, if that order is required, also determines construction and destruction order.

Comment: I can't find anything that explicitly says that order is required, but also nothing that says it is allowed to be different. As they're public members and definitely not marked "exposition only", none of the other clauses granting leeway to the implementation apply.  So, I'm going to have to fall on the side of that being the required order.

Comment: Looking at the draft C++0x standard, it does appear that that standard mandates that *first* be constructed prior to *second*.  Specifically, 20.3.3.4 `pair(); Effects: Initializes its members as if implemented: pair() : first(), second() {}`  I read that to mean order is defined, but I'll defer to a language lawyer.

Comment: @RSK: 20.2.2/1 is a stronger ordering requirement - the order in an initialization list doesn't influence and (unfortunately) doesn't need to match the actual initialization order, which is specified by the class member declaration.

Comment: @RSamuel: The order in the ctor initializer doesn't matter, it's member declaration order that determines initialization order. (And almost identical text is in the current standard at 20.2.2/2.)

Comment: @MichaelBurr And destruction order is specified to be opposite of initialization order, right?