# What is the order of object destruction if we pass user defined object in stl container?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

For checking the order of destruction of user defined object in stl container, I have tested following code

```
class A
{
public: 

    static int i;
    const int j;
    A():j(++i)
    {
        cout<<"A::A() "<< j <<endl;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        cout<<"A::~A(): "<< j <<endl;
    }
    A(const A & obj):j(++i)
    {
        cout<<"copyconstro " << j <<endl;
    }
};

int A::i = 0;
int main()
{
    vector<A> obj;
    A ab; //1
    A ad;// 2
    A c;//3
    obj.push_back(ab); //4

    vector<A> obj2;
    obj2.push_back(c); //5
}
```

output:

```
A::A() 1
A::A() 2
A::A() 3
copyconstro 4
copyconstro 5
A::~A(): 5
A::~A(): 3
A::~A(): 2
A::~A(): 1
A::~A(): 4
```

I am little confused after looking at output.

Does ISO C++ standard mandate any sort of destruction order of objects inside STL containers?

Answer (score 2):

The order of destruction is the reverse order in which they are constructed. In your function, the order of destruction is:

```
obj2
c
ad
ab
obj
```

When `obj2` gets destructed, it destructs 5.

When `c` gets destructed, it destructs 3.

When `ad` gets destructed, it destructs 2.

When `ab` gets destructed, it destructs 1.

When `obj` gets destructed, it destructs 4.

Comment: The question is about the order of object destruction inside STL containers, which is as TonyD pointed out [unspecified](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2083629/2507444).

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't illustrate anything about "destruction order of objects inside STL containers" - each container only has one element.  You're observing order of (creation and) destruction of function-local variables: notice destruction is the reverse of construction order, and specifically that construction of 4 happens when `obj` is defined, not when a copy of `ab` is `push_back`-ed into it, hence "4" being destroyed last.

Anyway, to actually answer your question - no - the Standard doesn't specify element destruction order.