# std::stack element destruction order

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any guarantee regarding the destruction order of std::stack elements?

I have a class that manages the lifetime of a set of services. Since there may be service interdependencies, the order of construction and destruction is important -- the services should be destroyed in the reverse order of their creation.

I thought I would use a `std::stack<std::unique_ptr<Service>>` for this purpose. Knowing that a stack is a container adapter, and guessing that this might affect its destruction semantics, I searched, but [I couldn't find any documentation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (page 800) that guaranteed the order of destruction for the elements of a std::stack.

In the end, I wrote a little test:

```
struct Squealer {
    Squealer() {
        static int instance_count = 0;
        this->instance = ++instance_count;
    }
    ~Squealer() {
        std::cout << "Destroying instance " << instance << std::endl;
    }
    int instance;
};

int main(int argc, char *[] argv) {
    {
        std::stack<Squealer> squealers;
        squealers.emplace();
        squealers.emplace();
        squealers.emplace();
    }
    std::cout << "...done" << std::endl;
}
```

The result was as expected:

```
Destroying instance 3
Destroying instance 2
Destroying instance 1
...done
```

Should I be relying on this behavior? Is the naive destruction order guaranteed for std::stack, or should I take the (admittedly easy) step of popping it until it is clear?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083603/stl-containers-element-destruction-order  This is about `vector`, `list` and `map` but I would guess that the same applies for `stack`

Comment: I saw that, but since `stack` is an adapter, I wondered if it would define additional behavior...not that I could find any documentation of that. If both `queue` and `stack` rely on `deque` and neither specifies element destruction order, the default element destruction order is going to be surprising for one of the two.

Comment: an ugly workaround would be to pop all the elements manually. Actually I wouldnt expect this to be much less efficient than calling the `stack` destructor

Comment: The destruction order is undefined by the standard. Stack is an adapter for implementation a vector, list or a deque can be used.

Comment: @Lenz I'll accept an answer to that effect -- I'm just not familiar enough with the standard to be confident that something is *undefined*, versus the possibility that I just *couldn't find* it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) isn't a Container, it's a Container Adapter. It takes as its second parameter which Container you actually want to use to store the elements:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::deque<T>
> class stack;
```

The destruction semantics of `stack<T>` would be those of `deque<T>`. This, however, doesn't really help you very much, since the destruction order of `deque<T>` is unspecified by the standard. Indeed, it's not specified for any of the sequence containers.

If destruction order is important, then you should do one of two things: either provide a new container that destroys its elements last to first:

```
template <class T>
struct my_deque : std::deque<T>
{
    using std::deque<T>::deque;

    ~my_deque() {
        while (!this->empty()) this->pop_back();
    }
};

template <class T>
using my_stack = std::stack<T, my_deque<T>>;
```

Or provide your own implementation of `stack` whose destructor pops all the elements:

```
template <class T, class Container = std::deque<T>>
struct ordered_stack : std::stack<T, Container>
{
    using std::stack<T, Container>::stack;

    ~ordered_stack() {
        while (!this->empty()) {
            this->pop();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Didn't immediately occur to me how easy it would be to enforce a destruction order by simply popping the elements. Simple and elegant solution, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

By default a `stack` is backed by a `deque` (23.6.6.1)

```
template <class T, class Container = deque<T>>
class stack {
```

A `deque` does not have a defined destruction order.

However, you can implement a simple container that supports the `stack`, you just need to provide `back`, `push_back`, and `pop_back`.