# What is the order of destruction of the two entries of a std::pair?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, std-pair, order-of-execution

Only 5 tags are allowed, but please, take it as [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) and [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) are in the list too, because I'd like to know about those standards as well, in case something has changed since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

Is the order of destruction of the two entries of a `std::pair` ([***not `std::tuple`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068546/c-stdtuple-order-of-destruction/39068642#39068642), nor [other containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083603/stl-containers-element-destruction-order)) specified by the standard? Where in [the standard draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/) can I find this information?

Also, in case the order is indeed specified, since when has it been?

In my GCC implementation I see this

```cpp
namespace std {
// ...
  template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
    struct pair
    : private __pair_base<_T1, _T2>
    {
      typedef _T1 first_type;    ///< The type of the `first` member
      typedef _T2 second_type;   ///< The type of the `second` member

      _T1 first;                 ///< The first member
      _T2 second;                ///< The second member
// ...
```

so it's clear that `second` is destroyed before `first`, but is it just a choice of GCC or is it mandated by the standard?

---

Actually, a quick search in the draft reveals that [§22.3.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/pairs.pair) shows what the `std::pair` class looks like, and it starts like this:

```cpp
namespace std {
  template<class T1, class T2>
  struct pair {
    using first_type  = T1;
    using second_type = T2;

    T1 first;
    T2 second;
```

Is it just an example? Or is it a mandate?

Comment: @nick ppl here appreciate at least elementary research effort, like opening `std::pair` standard section before asking the question

Comment: @LanguageLawyer, see comments under the non-delete answer.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact you've opened the relevant section only after asking the question

Answer (score 4):

The order is specified [in the Standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/pairs.pair):

```
template<class T1, class T2>
  struct pair {
    using first_type  = T1;
    using second_type = T2;

    T1 first;
    T2 second;
    //...
  }
```

The definitions of the members are not marked as "exposition only", hence, they are mandatory.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up finding it right before you posted, but thanks. I would actually ask: how do I know that that code is meant to be mandatory and not just an example? Would I have found a not telling it is just an example?

Comment: Generally, what's written in the Standard *is* the specification. Occasionally, however, there are blanket statements "We write A to mean B without implying C" in introductory sections. So, you can't be sure about the meaning of a paragraph unless you have read (and understood) the entire text of the Standard. In this particular case, I do not recall that an exception would be made, though.

Comment: Is a class synopsis like the one you quote actually normative? Because if so, I would expect that the order of the member functions should be respected as well, but both stdlibc++ and libc++ declare them in different orders. Though I suppose it makes no difference for member functions...

Comment: @Nelfeal, I guess I could ask _Is a class synopsis like the one you quote actually normative?_ as a separate question :D

Comment: @Nelfeal - There is also the "as-if"-rule. Can you detect function declaration order from your program? No?